# Searching windows registry using Regex

Tags: regex, registry

I need to use Regex for finding a specific value under all profile folders of HKU. For example `HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-2080281-3015743969-773635936-1109\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\ParseAutoExec`'. The problem is that it is preceded by the SID. If I use equals to operator it is working but it can be scoped to only one key at a time. 
I need a way to scan all the SIDs under the HKU folder looking for this value so I should not have to specify the individual SIDs. I have tried several options including 
 `/^.*\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\ParseAutoExec$/i`  Is there any way I can get this done without using Powershell ? Any help is most appreciated. Thank you !

Comment: What programming language are you using and what have you tried so far? Show us some code.

Comment: Hello Adrian..I am not using any programming language...We have a product from ArcSight that we use for auditing. This allows us to use  regular expressions in the parameters of a query to evaluate the required user accounts.

Comment: I don't get it, what is your question? What are the specifications? What are SIDs? And HKU is Hong Kong University right? What are you trying to match with regex anyway?